# Does Ubuntu server support encryption on arm devices?

Tags: server, encryption, arm

If I want to run Ubuntu Server on a Raspberry Pi4 can I encrypt the SD card like an encrypted disk? If not is the next best thing to encrypt the home directory?

Answer (score 8):

Yes encryption is *supported*.

However, the Pi4 bootloader cannot currently (late 2021) handle the normal Ubuntu Server installer. You must install LUKS and run cryptsetup manually after booting your newly-flashed system.

If you don't know how LUKS and cryptsetup work, review a few tutorials and perhaps practice in a VM before encrypting your real system.

Reminder: If booting from an SD card, recall that they wear out. The moment the SD card dies your encrypted data becomes forever inaccessible unless you are prepared.

Comment: But how to do it? You don't really explain how to do it.

Comment: @acmpo6ou Deliberately. If you need more detail than "*You must install LUKS and run cryptsetup manually after booting your newly-flashed system*", then you are not ready for the process. Much may go wrong.